# ASP:Hidden field variable from code behind loses value on return from server inside update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, hidden-field

I have a custom webpart that displays report data.  It lives inside a tab control, and inside an update panel so the call back to refresh the report data is async.

On the server, I need to process some data and send back a value for later use.  This variable just needs to SIT there and wait for user action, and then a client side javascript will use read the variable and  based on the condition of the variable, this javascript will programmatically "click" the button in the update panel.

#### THE UPDATE PANEL AND REPORT VIEWER ON THE PAGE

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:Button ID="btnSendHiddenField" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"  OnClick="btnSendHiddenField_Click"/>

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="383px" 
        InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="757px" 
        SizeToReportContent="True">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

<asp:HiddenField  ID= "hiddenCurrentObjectId"  runat="server"/>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**THE SERVER CODE THAT PROCESSES THE DATA AND SENDS BACK THE VARIABLE. I HAVE OMITTED THE UNRELATED CODE.**

```
Protected Sub btnSendHiddenField_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSendHiddenField.Click
                Dim parsedObjectId As String = ""
                parsedObjectId = "1000"
                hiddenCurrentObjectId.Value = parsedObjectId
End Sub
```

In my OnUnload code for the panel.  Which has to be there or there to make some other things work in the WebPart.  I borrowed this OnUnload code to overcome a previous issue.

#### MY ONUNLOAD FUNCTION

```
Protected Sub UpdatePanel_Unload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim methodInfo As MethodInfo = GetType(ScriptManager).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).Where(Function(i) i.Name.Equals("System.Web.UI.IScriptManagerInternal.RegisterUpdatePanel")).First()
    methodInfo.Invoke(ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page), New Object() {TryCast(sender, UpdatePanel)})
End Sub
End Class
```

#### THE PROBLEM

The value from the hidden field gets wiped out on the return trip.  I  think it is getting wiped on the OnUnload function call.

#### MY QUESTION

What can I do to preserve this hidden field value so the client side javascript can use it when another user generated event occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are lossing the hidden field value then simplest way it to store it in a ViewState of any Session value.

You can get the value in js as:

```
function GetSessionValue()
{
   var sessionValue = "<%=Session["ITEM"].ToString()%>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I considered that but I read that you can't pull the value of a session object out using java script. If I am wrong please let me know, or if you have an example of how to get it out I would appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: Why you need to pull the value of session object from javascript. You need to maintain this value at code behind only?

Comment: You can get the value in js as:
function GetSessionValue()
{
   var sessionValue = "<%=Session["ITEM"].ToString()%>";
}

Comment: Vikrants.  Thank you, I will try this and report back to you.  To answer your question, why I need to pull the value on the client side with javascript---the reason is that based on the value of the variable, I may or may not fire the button click event and cause a refresh.  I only want to refresh if the value I parse out of the JSON on the server does NOT match the current value on the client side.  Thanks again for your input and help.

Comment: Virkrants.  I modified the code to get the value, but it is coming back null.     Maybe it isn't making it out of the UpdatePanel?      var mySessionVar = ('<%= Session("objectId") %>').toString;
     var getJSONString = jQuery.parseJSON(mySessionVar);
     alert(getJSONString);

Comment: This code works if you don't have an update panel blocking you.  That is why I accepted the answer.  It may help someone else.